# No such table SQLite3

Tags: ios

My app has a SQLite database. I don’t know how to explain, but sometimes all tables from the sqlite file gets deleted. It happen frequently. The .db file still exists but no tables.

Comment: I would guess that the DB file has been deleted or you pointed `open` at the wrong path.  Remember, SQLite will silently recreate the DB file if it's not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tables in an SQLite database (for a given path) will be removed *only* in these two situations:

1. The DROP TABLE command was executed against the database
2. The database file was replaced with a version that did not contain the tables.

Alternatively, the code may be creating a *new* database or the opening the *wrong* database file. If there are *no* tables then a new database/file was probably created. The "relative path" can play a role in *where* the SQLite file is opened from.

Find out which situation is occurring - and fix it.